# Dart and Flutter plugin: Code completion is not working in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1

Tags: intellij-idea, intellisense, dart

Unfortunately, there is a problem with the code completion using Dart and Flutter plugins in the new version IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1. The weird thing is when the Class is written, IntelliJ can find the Dart package correctly, but when I try to write it from the start, the code completion doesn't work, IntelliJ say "No suggestions":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J87s.gif

Another thing, I don't know why the structure project although the Dart SDK and the flutter plugin are set up, IntelliJ insists to put a different SDK, in my case, JDK, I think the code completion is having problems because of this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLyhk.gif

Have ever you these problems? How have you solved it?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have anything to do with your second screenshot (I think that just has to do with normal Java projects in IntelliJ, which is not applicable here).

It looks like it's just a bug in the current stable version of the Flutter SDK (and the current Dart language version it uses). This bug does not appear to be present in the current beta version however. If you open a terminal into your project directory (it's easiest in IntelliJ by clicking `Terminal` at the bottom of your window) and write the following:

```
$ flutter channel beta
$ flutter upgrade
```

You'll switch to the current beta version of Flutter (with the corresponding Dart language version that seems to have the bug fixed). More information on changing Flutter channels [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels).

At the time of writing, using the beta channel, these are my current version numbers:

Flutter:
  • version: 1.3.8
  • channel beta
  • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Framework:
  • revision e5b1ed7a7f (4 weeks ago)
  • 2019-03-06 14:23:37 -0800

Engine:
  • revision f4951df193

Tools:
  • Dart 2.2.1 (build 2.2.1-dev.0.0 571ea80e11)

Doing the above fixed the problem for me, and now my code completion works as expected. Obviously you should be aware of the additional caveats of using non-stable build channels, but you can always switch back.

You can read more about how I figured out that I might need to upgrade my SDKs [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25820).

It looks like they've been making great changes lately. I guess the current stable version just has a bug (or it wasn't originally a feature?).

Comment: Thank you. An issue was created about this on GitHub and it was solved now, we need to upgrade our Dart plugin https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3338#event-2249495859